# SQL Join and select

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I am very new to SQL and I'm attempting to work through some exercises and I am having some trouble with the following problem:

There is a database consisting of six tables:

1. Author(AUTHOR ID, AUTHOR NAME, AUTHOR FIRSTNAME)
2. Book(BOOK ID, ISBN, TITLE, EDITOR, EDITION DATE) which contains the list of     books (ISBN attribute is the key).
3. Written(AUTHOR ID, BOOK ID) which is the list of books written by each author.
4. Copy(BOOK ID, COPY ID, STATUS, ACQ DATE) which contains the list of copies for each book.
5. Borrower(USER ID, USER NAME, USER FIRSTNAME, USER ADDRESS) which contains the list of borrowers.
6. Borrowing(BOOK ID, COPY ID, USER ID, BORROWING DATE) which contains the list of
   borrowing in the library.

With these tables I am trying to accomplish a few queries:

1. Search the titles of books written by Ernest Hemingway
2. Search the id, name and first name of borrowers which borrow the book with id 10
3. Search the number currently borrowing.
4. Then for each book, search the id, title and number of copies which have the status borrowed

For the first one I used:
SELECT title FROM Book
WHERE Author='Ernest Hemingway

For the thrid:
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT book id) FROM Borrowing

I'm a little stumped on the remaining two (I'm a little confused on the join method) and I wanted to make sure these other two queries were correct as well.  Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks guys!

Comment: Please post what you have tried for the other two queries and also pick either mysql or sql-server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To start with the join you can use [this schema](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/Visual_SQL_Joins/Visual_SQL_JOINS_orig.jpg).

Answer (score 1):

the answer of first question

```
SELECT 
    title 
FROM book b, author a, written w 
WHERE b.bookid = w.bookid AND a.authorid = w.authorid AND authorname = 'Ernest Hemingway';
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow.  Please, always, explain your answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you're familiar with the way scoping works in other languages, you can use the same principals for SQL.

So as a strict sample

```
SELECT USER_ID, USER_NAME, USER_FIRSTNAME
FROM BORROWER
WHERE BORROWING.BOOK_ID = 10
```

Answer (score 0):

The second one will look something like:

```
SELECT a.userID, a.userName, a.userFirstName
FROM Borrower a JOIN Borrowing b ON a.userID = b.userID
WHERE b.bookID = 10
```

There are a lot of resources online that can help with joins, I suggest checking out http://www.w3schools.com/sql/default.asp